# does shrink_to_fit() function removes null pointers?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2019, unique-ptr

I wanted to ask you about the vector::shrink_to_fit() function.

Lets say i've got a vector of pointers to objects (or unique_ptr in my case)
and i want to resize it to the amount of objects that it stores.

At some point i remove some of the objects from the vector by choice using the release() function of unique_ptr
so there is a null pointer in that specific place in the vector as far as i know.

So i want to resize it and remove that null pointer in between the elements of the vector and i'm asking if i could do that with shrink_to_fit() function?

Comment: Are you asking how to resize the vector and remove everything past the new end point, or do you have disjoint null pointers that you need to go through and collectively remove while leaving the other elements along the way in the vector? Or is it neither of those? `shrink_to_fit` is specifically for capacity, not size.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` does not remove null pointers.  Before you shrink, you'll want to [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) the null pointers.

Comment: how do you erase them? i just want to shrink my vector to prevent having null pointers in between the elements but for some reason the vector didn't allow me to erase or remove the specific element because it's a unique_ptr vector.

Comment: @alexbutane: how did you try to 'erase or remove the specific element'? please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end the solution that i found was simple:

```
void Controller::delete_allocated_memory(int index)
{
    m_vec.erase(m_vec.begin() + index);
    m_vec.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

it works fine even if the vector is made of unique_ptrs, as far as i know it doesn't even create the null pointer that i was talking about and it shifts left all existing objects in the vector.

what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

No, [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) does not change the contents or size of the vector. All it might do is release some of its internal memory back to a lower level library or the OS, etc. behind the scenes. It may invalidate iterators, pointers, and references, but the only other change you might see would be a reduction of `capacity()`. It's also valid for `shrink_to_fit` to do absolutely nothing at all.

It sounds like you want the ["Erase-remove" idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), nullptr), vec.end());
```

The `std::remove` shifts all the elements which don't compare equal to `nullptr` left, filling the "gaps". But it doesn't change the vector's size; instead it returns an iterator to the position in the vector just after the sequence of shifted elements; the rest of the elements still exist but have been moved from.  Then the `erase` member function gets rid of those unnecessary end elements, reducing the vector's size.

Or as @chris notes, C++20 adds an [`erase` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) to `std::vector` and a related `erase_if`, which makes things easier. They may already be supported in MSVC 2019. Using the new `erase` could just look like:

```
vec.erase(nullptr);
```

Comment: Note that since OP is using VS2019, it's likely that `std::erase_if` is available, which avoids the need for the idiom.

Comment: I meant `std::erase`, my bad. The point is the new version. It is a free function, though, not a member overload.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Question askers get to check whatever answer they found most helpful, independent of votes.

Answer (score 0):

This quick test show that u can't do like this.

```
int x = 1;
vector<int*> a;
cout << a.capacity() << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   a.push_back(&x);
}
cout << a.capacity() << endl;
a[9] = nullptr;
a.shrink_to_fit();
cout << a.capacity() << endl;
```

Result:

```
0
16
10
```

Comment: Printing the size and/or contents afterward would be more conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

> `m_gates[index].release(); m_gates.shrink_to_fit();`

Based on your comment, what you're looking for is simply to erase this single element from your vector right then and there. Replace both of these statements with:

```
m_gates.erase(m_gates.begin() + index);
```

Or a more generic version if swapping containers in the future is a possibility:

```
using std::begin;
m_gates.erase(std::next(begin(m_gates), index));
```

`erase` supports iterators rather than indices, so there's a conversion in there. This will remove the pointer from the vector while calling its destructor, which causes `unique_ptr` to properly clean up its memory.

Now erasing elements one by one could potentially be a performance concern. If it does end up being a concern, you can do what you were getting at in the question and null them out, then remove them all in one go later on:

```
m_gates[index].reset();

// At some point in the program's future:
std::erase(m_gates, nullptr);
```

---

What you have right now is highly likely to be a memory leak. `release` releases *ownership* of the managed memory, meaning you're now responsible for cleaning it up, which isn't what you were looking for. Both `erase` and `reset` (or equivalently, `= {}` or `= nullptr`) will actually call the destructor of `unique_ptr` while it still has ownership and properly clean up the memory. `shrink_to_fit` is for vector capacity, not size, and is unrelated.